# Access json array from navigator.camera.getPicture Cordova response

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am getting a response after I run a function that calls a cordova **navigator.camera.getPicture()** function. All works well and the response is below, however I can not access individual value-pairs

```
({"tagone" : "optimal", "datex" : "Thursday"})
```

I try this: **r.response['tagone']** and just returns empty.

```
 $scope.win = function (r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);

    $("#camLoader").hide();
    $("#resultDiv").show();
    $("#finalResult").append(r.response['tagone']);


    //alert(r.response);
};
```

Comment: you might want to provide more code if you want an answer

Comment: added more code, however like I said the response is coming back ok, and is exactly as the json response above when I output from r.response. However, I want to access individual value-pairs...which I cant seem to do

Comment: if you console.log(r.response['tagone']) what do u get?

Comment: I get "undefined" in console

Comment: there must be something else, as u can see in this fiddle getting the property of the r.response is clearly not a problem. https://jsfiddle.net/zuswc1t2/. How do u call `navigator.camera.getPicture()`?

Comment: cameraSuccess callback returns a string, not a JSON object